# "This Monday Tom was late. But next Monday he won't be late." — Would it remain correct, if we used "next Mondays" instead of "next Monday"?

Tags: articles, time-words

I'd like to know if the appearance of a plural noun after "next"  affects articles.
For this purpose, I came up with the following example:

Today is Monday. Tom goes to chess on Mondays. He was late today. He says:
**(1)** ***Next Monday** I won't be late*. — correct
**(2)** ***The next Monday** I won't be late*. — incorrect

These two sentences have a singular "Monday".
I know that since "next" is used relative to the current moment, we must use it without "the".
But would the things remain the same if we used "Mondays"?

**(3)** ***Next Mondays** I won't be late*.
Is (3) still correct?
If not, then why not?

**(4)** ***The next Mondays** I won't be late*.
Is (4) still incorrect?
If not, then why not?

---

Update:
The aim of this question is to understand whether "next + a time-word in plural" can be used without "the".

Answer (score 1):

**Next Monday** is a single day. We wouldn't normally use *next* to refer to all successive Mondays. Tom would probably say "In future, I won't be late".

To *really* spell it out, you could say "Next Monday, and on all the Mondays after..."

Comment: The aim of this question is to understand whether "next + a time-word in plural" can be used without "the". Maybe the following sentences (with the word "classes") will seem more idiomatic to you: **(5)** "_Next classes I won't be late_." and **(6)** "_**The** next classes I won't be late_." Which of (5) & (6) is correct and which is not? Thanks.

Comment: The same applies. You could say "The next two classes will be taken by Mr Smith", but not "Next classes" (with or without 'the') to refer to all the following ones.

Comment: "_The next two classes will be taken by Mr Smith_" : in this sentence the word "_classes_" doesn't relate to time. So unfortunately, it doesn't help to sort out the original question.

Comment: _Class_ is not a 'time-word' in any context, though it could be understood to mean 'the date of the next class' in some contexts. I don't find either (5) or (6) idiomatic.

Comment: I didn't say "class" _is_ time; I said "class" can _relate_ to time.

Answer (score 1):

No, **Mondays** (a fossilized genitive construction, cf. German *Montags*) means  "every Monday", Monday as a day of the week ("Which day of the week does the show air? -- It airs Mondays") not any *particular* Monday.

> Mondays the friends have lunch together.

That is, "Every Monday the friends have lunch together".

The word "next" is semantically inapplicable: *next [every Monday] <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

You would need some sort of determining count phrase if you wish to refer to a particular group of Mondays:

> *The next three Mondays* I'll be out of town.

Comment: Can I say your example without "the": "_Next three Mondays I'll be out of town._" ? Thanks.

Comment: "Next three Mondays" is heard in informal speech in American English, not sure about other dialects.  I would hear it as grammatical in conversation but wouldn't use it in any context requiring neutral or formal register.

Comment: When we talk relative to the current moment: "_**Next Monday** I'll be out of town_" — correct; "_**The next Monday** I'll be out of town_" — incorrect. By this rule: "_**Next three Mondays** I'll be out of town_" — must be correct too; "_**The next three Mondays** I'll be out of town_" — must be incorrect too. Why does the rule cease working when it comes to plural nouns? Thanks.

Comment: "The next Monday I'll be out of town" is grammatical. If you're looking at your calendar a few months out, say, and discussing it with someone over the phone, and your focus is on Monday, 12 February 2024, for example, you could say "Monday the 12th I'm available but the next Monday I'll be out of town".  There, "Monday" refers to the day of the week, not to a particular Monday. That is, "the next Monday *in that month*".

Comment: Compare: "Every August much of Europe would shut down for holiday, unlike *Augusts* in the US, where it was business as usual." The plural can refer to multiples of the month-in-the-year, as it does there, or it can be a fossilized genitive that means "every August":  "*Augusts* they would close the shop and take a holiday."

Comment: I know that "_**The** next Monday I'll be out of town_" can be correct, that's why I wrote "when we talk relative to the current moment". In this case, it's incorrect. But with a plural "_Mondays_" the sentence, for some strange reason, becomes correct with "the": "_**The** next three Monday**s** I'll be out of town_". Why is it going on so?

Comment: I didnt know what you meant by "relative to the current moment".

Comment: As I wrote earlier, "... some determining count phrase".   "Three" makes it grammatical.

Comment: @Lambie  "for" is certainly idiomatic but its omission is not unidiomatic.   I'll be gone three days.  I'll be gone for three days.  Both equally idiomatic.

Comment: Sure with or without **for**.

Answer (score 0):

What must be looked at is the **broader context** of usage in terms of pragmatics:

> Pragmatics deals with utterances, by which we will mean specific
> events, the intentional acts of speakers at times and places,
> typically involving language. Logic and semantics traditionally deal
> with properties of types of expressions, and not with properties that
> differ from token to token, or use to use, or, as we shall say, from
> utterance to utterance, and vary with the particular properties that
> differentiate them. Pragmatics is sometimes characterized as dealing
> with the effects of context. This is equivalent to saying it deals
> with utterances, if one collectively refers to all the facts that can
> vary from utterance to utterance as ‘context.’ One must be careful,
> however, for the term is often used with more limited meanings.
> [pragramatics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pragmatics/)

[That definition above is from a philosophy site because the Wikipedia entry was not great and the definition in linguistics is basically the same].

Sometimes, a single sentence does not establish enough context.

So: **sample questions**

"(1) Next Monday I won't be late. — correct
(2) The next Monday I won't be late. — incorrect"

Pragmatic situations
Yes, (1) is correct. But the context has to be assumed to be **something like**:
Pers. 1 "This Monday you were so late!" Pers. 2: "Next Monday, I won't be late, I promise."

(2) can also be correct:
(2) The next Monday I won't be late.

- "I was late every Monday this month. But the next Monday [that comes around] I won't be late".
  OR (4)
- "I was late every Monday last month. But the next Mondays, I won't be late".

However, (3) is agrammatical for *next*, when it means: **immediately adjacent (as in place, rank, or time)** has to be followed by a singular noun *unless there is a determiner*.

So: *"Next Mondays* I won't be late". **doesn't work** whereas "the next Mondays" (see above) does. For *next* to go with a plural noun, there must be a determiner:
**The next people** in line were not nice.
**The next movies** he saw were terrible.

"I was late all Mondays in November, but *the next Mondays* I wasn't".