# "<Next> <The next> <The following> six months will be the hardest." — What's the difference between these variants?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, definite-article

[ell.stackexchange.com](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/345419/82229):
**(1)** ***The next** three Mondays I'll be out of town*. — common
[ell.stackexchange.com](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345408/this-monday-tom-was-late-but-next-monday-he-wont-be-late-would-it-remain/345419?noredirect=1#comment668681_345419):
**(2)** ***Next** three Mondays I'll be out of town*. — informal
I was told (1) and (2) mean the same where (2) is just an informal version of (1).

my variant:
**(3)** ***The following** three Mondays I'll be out of town*.
Is (3) correct?
If it is, does (3) mean the same as (1)?

---

Also I'd like to consider the following examples.

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/next_1):
**(4)** ***The next** six months will be the hardest*.
As far as I understand, since today is 18 December 2023, the hardest time will be approximately from today to 18 June 2024.
Am I right?
If not, then why not?

---

my variant:
**(5)** ***Next** six months will be the hardest*.

By analogy with (1) and (2):
(4) and (5) mean the same.
(5) is just an informal version of (4).
Am I right?
If not, then why not?

---

my variant:
**(6)** ***The following** six months will be the hardest*.
Is (6) correct?
If it is, does (6) mean the same as (4)?

Comment: Most of your examples aren't very idiomatic because we wouldn't normally "front" the time-based adverbial. It's more natural to say *"I'll be out of town **for the next three Mondays**".*

Comment: "The following three Mondays" refers to three Mondays in succession immediately after a *specified future date*, as Kate mentions in her answer, whereas "(the) next three Mondays" could be in relation to "today" or to a future date.  The same is true with other calendar items, "months", "quarters".  With "the following" there must be a future time as the "anchor".

Comment: Or a past time, just not today.  "On Monday, May 2, 2022 I was in Barcelona. The following|next three Mondays I was in London." Same is true with "previous". It  must be anchored by a specified date other than today.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice From your comments I'm inferring that the following example can be both with "the" and without "the": "_On Monday, January 1, 2024 I will be in Barcelona. **(The) next three Mondays** I will be in London_." Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the parentheses there `(the) next three Mondays` indicates that the definite article is optional, with the caveat that omitting it is informal/conversational, as you mentioned in your question.  I should probably say "conversational and terse".

Answer (score 1):

To me, *the following three Mondays* means 'the three Mondays after a certain date', not 'the next three after today'.

> On January 8th and the next three Mondays I shall be out of town.

Comment: Does "the following six months" in "_The following six months will be the hardest_." also mean "'the six months after a certain date", not "the next six after now"? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it does to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, just a little too formal to be most people's first choice of words. It kind of makes me want to rewrite the examples to "the following three Mondays I will not be present" and "the following six months will be the most difficult" to match the style.